# Printing hash value in Perl

Tags: perl, loops, hash, foreach, key-value

When I print a variable, I am getting a `HASH(0xd1007d0)` value. I need to print the values of all the keys and values. However, I am unable to as the control does not enter the loop.

```
foreach my $var(keys %{$HashVariable}){
    print"In the loop \n";
    print"$var and $HashVariable{$var}\n";

}
```

But the control is not even entering the loop. I am new to perl.

Comment: you are getting referencing the hashes in scalar?

Comment: If the variable `$HashVariable` is indeed a hashref the only possibility is that it is empty, without any keys.  Otherwise the code would get in the loop.

Comment: could you please share the hash where is getting from

Comment: Show us the output of `print Dumper($HashVariable);`

Comment: @emma: We really need to see how the variable `$HashVariable` is constructed. Without that all our answers are guesses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't answer completely, because it depends entirely on what's in `$HashVariable`.

The easiest way to tell what's in there is:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $HashVariable;
```

Assuming this is a hash *reference* - which it would be, if `print $HashVariable` gives `HASH(0xdeadbeef)` as an output.

So this *should* work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $HashVariable = { somekey => 'somevalue' }; 

foreach my $key ( keys %$HashVariable ) { 
   print $key, " => ", $HashVariable->{$key},"\n";
}
```

The  only mistake you're making is that `$HashVariable{$key}` won't work - you need to dereference, because as it stands it refers to `%HashVariable` not `$HashVariable` which are two completely different things.

Otherwise - if it's not entering the loop - it may mean that `keys %$HashVariable` isn't returning anything. Which is why that `Dumper` test would be useful - is there any chance you're either not populating it correctly, or you're *writing* to `%HashVariable` instead.

E.g.:

```
my %HashVariable;
$HashVariable{'test'} = "foo";
```

Answer (score 3):

There's an obvious problem here, but it wouldn't cause the behaviour that you are seeing.

You think that you have a hash reference in `$HashVariable` and that sounds correct given the `HASH(0xd1007d0)` output that you see when you print it.

But setting up a hash reference and running your code, gives slightly strange results:

```
my $HashVariable = {
  foo => 1,
  bar => 2,
  baz => 3,
};

foreach my $var(keys %{$HashVariable}){
    print"In the loop \n";
    print"$var and $HashVariable{$var}\n";
}
```

The output I get is:

```
In the loop 
baz and 
In the loop 
bar and 
In the loop 
foo and
```

Notice that the values aren't being printed out. That's because of the problem I mentioned above. Adding `use strict` to the program (which you should always do) tells us what the problem is.

```
Global symbol "%HashVariable" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %HashVariable"?) at hash line 14.
Execution of hash aborted due to compilation errors.
```

You are using `$HashVariable{$var}` to look up a key in your hash. That would be correct if you had a hash called `%HashVariable`, but you don't - you have a hash reference called `$HashVariable` (note the `$` instead of `%`). To look up a key from a hash reference, you need to use a dereferencing arrow - `$HashVariable->{$var}`.

Fixing that, your program works as expected.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $HashVariable = {
  foo => 1,
  bar => 2,
  baz => 3,
};

foreach my $var(keys %{$HashVariable}){
    print"In the loop \n";
    print"$var and $HashVariable->{$var}\n";
}
```

And I see:

```
In the loop 
bar and 2
In the loop 
foo and 1
In the loop 
baz and 3
```

The only way that you could get the results you describe (the `HASH(0xd1007d0)` output but no iterations of the loop) is if you have a hash reference but the hash has no keys.

So (as I said in a comment) we need to see how your hash reference is created.